# How can i mock Pressable react native component?

Tags: react-native, testing, mocking, ts-jest

I use Pressable in my component and my jest tests are responding with such errors:

1. The above error occurred in the  component
2. Error: Unable to find node on an unmounted component

It's all because i use Pressable component, but if i remove it then test will work fine without errors